# Framework similar to DMTCP for windows

Tags: linux, windows, distributed-computing, checkpoint

DMTCP (Distributed MultiThreaded Checkpointing) is a tool to transparently checkpoint the state of multiple simultaneous applications, including multi-threaded and distributed applications. It is only available for linux. Is there any similar tool for windows ?

Comment: There are no Windows solutions for checkpointing. However, if you are familiar with Windows systems development, I can provide you some pointer on how to get started on porting DMTCP to Windows :-).